# PDE with Neumanm boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Sovle this PDE with Neumanm boundary condition.
\begin{cases}
    \begin{array}{l}
    u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0,f(t)<x<t. \\
    u(t,t)=\phi(t)\\
    u(f(t),t)=\psi(t)   
    \end{array}
\end{cases}
Here $f(t)$ is a curve with the following features:
$f(t)\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$;
Its graphic is between $x=t$ and $x=-t$; $|f'(t)|\neq 1$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$

I have tried to solve this problem by letting $u(x,t)=F(x+t)+G(x-t)$. Therefore, I get
\begin{cases}
    \begin{array}{l}
    F(2t)+G(0)=\phi(t)\\
    F(f(t)+t)+G(f(t)-t)=\psi(t)
    \end{array}
\end{cases}
It's easy to obtain that $F(x)=\phi(\frac{x}{2})-G(0)$ from the first equation. However, it seems
difficult to obtain $G(x)$ from the equations above.

Comment: You do not use the remaining assumptions? you might want to try to differentiate both identities and see what happens...

Comment: And $x=-t$? Is it useful?